# JavaScript media queries

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am trying to reduce the cube size for small screens using media queries.
I gave media queries in js since my cube-size is set in js,
but my cube size is not reducing when I decrease the browser window.
Can you tell me why its not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8YK2n/embedded/result/

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() { location.reload();

     Gallery.setOptions({
            size: 78,
            lightbox: false,
            //animation:  'drop'
            //speed:      500,
            //closeOnEsc: true,
            //slideshow:  false,
            //slideshow_speed: 3000,
            //cube_speed: 1000
        });

 });

if (screen.width < 600) {

     $(window).bind('resize', function() { location.reload();

     Gallery.setOptions({
            size: 25,
            lightbox: false,
            //animation:  'drop'
            //speed:      500,
            //closeOnEsc: true,
            //slideshow:  false,
            //slideshow_speed: 3000,
            //cube_speed: 1000
        });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're using `location.reload()`, which will refresh the page and not run any of the subsequent code?

---

You're also doing the check *outside* of the `resize` handler, so you only bind the appropriate handler based on the window's *original* size.  (Actually, if the window is smaller than 600, you'll bind *both* handlers and they'll both run!)  You probably want that `if` inside your handler.

FYI, this isn't a "media query"; those are a specific new feature with a particular syntax ported from CSS.  `screen` is an ancient DOM0 thing.

Also I've gotta say the endlessly rotating cube is pretty annoying.

Comment: in my code i commented it but still its not working........http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8YK2n/1/

Comment: can you write a small code so that it will be helpful for my understanding....thank u